# Is it possible to start an application in the way I am trying?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently making an Android launcher and have spent a lot of time on Stackoverflow on how to go about doing different things. However I have hit a snag with opening applications from my own. The code I used was pieced together from other questions on this topic. I now have a list of installed apps, but when clicked, my own app is reopened. I figure I am using the wrong intent in the wrong way but do not know how to fix the problem. So my questions is:
What would be a better way of opening a selected app? Below is the code that was used. NOTE: I am a beginner in coding.

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List < String > myList = new ArrayList < String > ();
ArrayList < ResolveInfo > list = (ArrayList < ResolveInfo > ) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
for (ResolveInfo rInfo: list) {
    System.out.println("Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm).toString() + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    myList.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());


}

ListView lists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.content);
ArrayAdapter < String > aa = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
lists.setAdapter(aa);

lists.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());

        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: The `getPackageName()` method returns the package name of the current `Activity` which is why `getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName())` is simply restarting your own app. After enumerating the other apps, you need to get *their* package names and use the one from the list item which is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written wonderful code but only mistake you have done is

```
i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
startActivity(i);
```

Here all your efforts get wasted because You are perfectly displaying all application names but onClick of Application name you are executing above code.But `getPackageName()`will return current activity package name hense no matter on which item you click it will restart your application.

So Just change

```
 i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
```

To This

```
i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(list.get(position).activityInfo.packageName);
```

It will start application on which you clicked!.